# jquery css get dynamically set properties

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic

I'm trying to get a css property that was dynamically set with jquery.

Consider this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#clickme").click(function(){

    $("#myTable").css('borderStyle','solid');
    $("#myTable").css('borderColor','black');
    $("#myTable").css('borderWidth','3px');
});

$("#clickme2").click(function(){
    alert($("#myTable").css('borderWidth'));
});

});
```

Clicking on clickme button will set the table myTable
with the expected properties (3px solid black),
but then clicking on clickme2 won't get
the 3px value !
Do you know any fix ?

I read here [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)

that a solution could be using the .style of the DOM element,
but if jquery could do it, I would prefer the jquery way ...

(the wysiwig for stackoverflow is a very good idea ;))

Comment: Note that your code can be improved/simplified as `$('#myTable').css({ borderStyle:'solid', borderColor:'black', borderWidth:'3px' });`

Comment: What happens when you click on clickme2?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is when you set a value with "borderWidth," it's a shorthand way of setting "borderTopWidth," "borderRightWidth," "borderBottomWidth," and "borderLeftWidth" all at once.

Therefore, I think you have to specify which side of the border you want to get, such as "borderBottomWidth."

Answer (score 0):

There is no actual value `borderWidth` or `border-width` it is a CSS shorthand property to set the four underlying properties `border-top-width`, `border-right-width` etc.

Thus you can only query for one of those four values:

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/zu74F/

Comment: ok, thanx,then for the border width I found alert($("#myTable").get(0).style.borderWidth); useful